Is it normal for svchost.exe to frequently access AMSI-related registry keys? (Windows 11)
I noticed that on my Windows 11 system, svchost.exe repeatedly attempts to access AMSI-related registry keys. When I disconnect my laptop from the internet, these access attempts stop.
I’m concerned after watching a video that mentioned some malware might try to use svchost.exe to disable AMSI for malicious purposes. However, I wonder if this might be normal network-related behavior in my case.
I’ve attached a screenshot from Process Monitor that captures the relevant access attempts.
Is this expected behavior in Windows 11, or could it indicate a potential infection?
Process Monitor:


Yes, it is normal. See Antimalware Scan Interface (AMSI) - Win32 apps | Microsoft Learn

@DavidPostill thanks for your answering. You made my day :))
